# json key with array of values - how to parse

Tags: json, vb.net

This is the json data I am trying to parse. (I did trim the imagedata down for example purposes)

```
{"imageData":["SUkqAORlAACGniG0JCHeSTV9icwWxF+N9AwzcsTDlLu+PeYCgeZXAP//","sfsdfsdyfhh2h43h8ysdfsdnvjknjfdsfdsf"]}
```

Any idea on how to parse it into a strongly typed class in .NET?

I am using the newtonsoft.json

I tried the following

```
Public Class DAFGImages
Public imageData As List(Of String)
End Class

 Dim DAFGImages As List(Of DAFGImages) = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, GetType(List(Of DAFGImages)))
```

Comment: This is the error I am getting - Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CarrierWebService.DAFGImages]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class already contains a List of string, so you dont need a list of DAFGImages too.  I would change the class member to a property:

```
Public Class DAFGImages
    Public Property imageData As List(Of String)
End Class
```

Then:

```
Dim jstr = ... from wherever
Dim myImgs = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DAFGImages)(jstr)
```

`myImgs.ImageData` will contain the 2 elements.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thank you coding wizards!